# wordpress http to https windows server

Tags: ssl, https, windows

Having a few issues getting things to work after changing wordpress from http to https on a windows sever. The web.config file is a bit of a mare to work with and the hosting company seems to think that changing http to https in wordpress settings is the only change necessary. currently I can only get the site to load css/js files on any pages other than the homepage by using default permalinks. and when I try adding http to https redirects in the web-config it causes even more problems. I've exhausted google so any advice appreciated.

Comment: define('FORCE_SSL_ADMIN', true);

Comment: hi, yes that's already in my wp-config file - the issue I think is having to use web.config rather than htaccess

Answer (score 0):

for anyone interested the hosting company is going to convert wp install to linux so that should sort things.

found this plugin https://wordpress.org/plugins/really-simple-ssl/ which could be good for anyone having issues on linux.

Answer (score 0):

Put this in your web.config:

```
<system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>

<rule name="HTTP to HTTPS redirect" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="(.*)" />
                    <conditions>
                        <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" ignoreCase="true" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}"
                        redirectType="Permanent" />
                </rule>
</rules>
<outboundRules>
                <rule name="Add Strict-Transport-Security when HTTPS" enabled="true">
                    <match serverVariable="RESPONSE_Strict_Transport_Security"
                        pattern=".*" />
                    <conditions>
                        <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="on" ignoreCase="true" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Rewrite" value="max-age=31536000" />
                </rule>
            </outboundRules>
    </rewrite>
  </system.webServer>
```